# How to replace a UIButton image with a photo taken from ImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I created a button, that when pressed brings up the camera. The user is supposed to take a photo, and then this photo is supposed to replace the image of the button. However, the camera takes the photo and when it is dismissed the image of the button remains unchanged, here is my code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
    UIButton *uploadPhotobutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [uploadPhotobutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploadphotoicon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    uploadPhotobutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);

    uploadPhotobutton.clipsToBounds = YES;

    uploadPhotobutton.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2.0f;
    uploadPhotobutton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.102 green:.737 blue:.612 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    uploadPhotobutton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    [self.view addSubview:uploadPhotobutton];
    [uploadPhotobutton setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 128)];
    [uploadPhotobutton addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadPhotoButton:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    UIImage *userImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [uploadPhotoButton setImage:userImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Any idea where the problem lies?

Comment: Your problem is not the button image but the button itself. This code is not going to even compile.

Comment: @Desdenova The code compiles and runs,and the button brings up the camera, the only thing is that the image is not replaced on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the uploadPhotoButton declared in

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

the same with uploadPhotoButton in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

?

Maybe it's not!